# Breezejs .net core 3 saving new entities issue

Tags: breeze, ef-core-3.1

using BreezeJs for .net core 3.1
Issue with fixupKeys when saving new entity
throws "Unable to locate the following fully qualified EntityType name: "

Examining this: the _entityGroupMap entries use another fully qualified format than the keymappings object 
e.g.
HoseColor:#Urflex.Webshop.Model (_entityGroupMap) <<==>> Urflex.Webshop.Model.HoseColor (keymappings)

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

problem solved. Overlooked some configuration in startup.cs file of the web api project.
As the breeze documentation states:

```
var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc();
  services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
        {
            // Set Breeze defaults for entity serialization
            var ss = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(opt.SerializerSettings);
            if (ss.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver resolver)
            {
                resolver.NamingStrategy = null;  // remove json camelCasing; names are converted on the client.
            }
            ss.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; // format JSON for debugging
        });

        // Add Breeze exception filter to send errors back to the client
        mvcBuilder.AddMvcOptions(o => { o.Filters.Add(new GlobalExceptionFilter()); });
```